# laravel 4 how to implements repository for polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel-4, repository-design

I have vehicle class morphTo(Bus) and MorphTo(SUV) and MorphTo(Sedan).

When saving in VehicleController, I called vehicleRepositoryInterface, vehicleRepository.

How can I save Bus or SUV or Sedan data?

My Vehicle Class

```
Class Vehicle controller{
    public function get_create(){
     if($this->vehicle->create(Input::all()))
          return Redirect::to()
    }
          return Redirect::to()->withInput()->withErrors($this->vehicle->getMessages());
}
```

My Vehicle Repository Class How to handle if(Vehicle Type is Bus / SUV / Van) with morphTo relation?

```
Class VehicleRepository Implements VehicleRepositoryInterface{
    public function create($array $inputs){
         if($this->validatator->IsValid($inputs)){
              // How to implement BUS or SUV or Van in here
                $this->model->create($inputs);
                return true;
         } 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I got answer myself for polymorphic relation to save in repository.

In create function--
   if($this->validator->isValid($attributes){}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer myself for polymorphic relation to save in repository.

In create function--

```
  if($this->validator->isValid($inputs){
      // first store in temp model. $this model will be destroyed.
       $temp_model = $this->model->create($inputs);
      //then Depency Injection comein for polymorphic model
       $this->polymorphicmodel->create($subinputs):
       // link with polymorphic relation
       $this->polymorphicmodel->modelable()->save($temp_model);
       return true;
    }
   return false;
```

really appreciate advanced modification or suggestion for better approached.